# How to make a curved line go from left to right to left down my document? Like my picture but not have the overflowing line on top of each corner

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I'm trying to get a green line to go down my document from left to right and back to left again.

Currently have three divs stacked and use border radius for the curves. However because this solution is three different divs, I can't get a continuous line using border radius.

Does anyone have a smarter solution?

Picture of what I have:

[image: picture of my current implementation]

```css
#featureHighlight {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.highlightedFeature {
  height: 150px;
  width: 96.5%;
}

#highlightedFeature1 {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 5px solid #23ce6bff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #23ce6bff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 450px;
}

#highlightedFeature2 {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: 5px solid #23ce6bff;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #23ce6bff;
  border-top-right-radius: 450px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 450px;
}

#highlightedFeature3 {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 5px solid #23ce6bff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div id="featureHighlight">
  <div id="highlightedFeature1" class="highlightedFeature"></div>
  <div id="highlightedFeature2" class="highlightedFeature"></div>
  <div id="highlightedFeature3" class="highlightedFeature"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about not putting extra stuff into the DOM but creating that pattern with background-images - using various types of gradient and repetition?

Comment: Hoping to find a purely css / code alternative instead of images. Tried a few things and am able to get straight lines. However no curved ones yet

Comment: For curved lines you use radial and conic gradients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various background-images created with linear-, radial- and conic- gradients.

This snippet gives an illustration where it's known that 4 horizontal lines are to be shown, with two left hand semi circles and one right hand one.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  --l: 4px;
  /* the height of the green line */
  ;
  --a: calc(var(--l) / 2);
  --h: calc((100vh - var(--l)) / 3);
  /* define the height between horizontal lines (also = diameter of the circles)..*/
  --w: calc(100vw - var(--h));
  /*..from which we can calculate the width of the horizontal lines */
  --r: calc(var(--h) / 2);
  /* .and the radius of the circles) */
  --h2: calc(2 * var(--h));
  --minusr: calc(-1 * var(--r));
  background-image: linear-gradient(lime 0 var(--l), transparent var(--l) 100%), conic-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50% 100%), radial-gradient(transparent 0 calc(var(--r) - 2.5px), lime calc(var(--r) - var(--a)) calc(var(--r) + var(--a)), transparent calc(var(--r) + var(--a)) 100%), conic-gradient(transparent 50%, black 50% 100%), radial-gradient(transparent 0 calc(var(--r) - var(--a)), lime calc(var(--r) - var(--a)) calc(var(--r) + var(--a)), transparent calc(var(--r) + var(--a)) 100%);
  background-size: var(--w) var(--h), var(--h2) var(--h2), var(--h2) var(--h2), var(--h2) var(--h2), var(--h2) var(--h2);
  background-repeat: no-repeat repeat, no-repeat repeat, no-repeat repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center top, calc(var(--minusr) + var(--a)) calc(var(--minusr) + var(--a)), calc(var(--minusr) + var(--a)) calc(var(--minusr) + var(--a)), calc(100% - var(--r) + var(--h) - var(--a)) center, calc(100% - var(--r) + var(--h) - var(--a)) center;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

This gives a background:

[image]

Comment: Very impressive, honestly next level. It's hard for me to wrap my head around. Where do you define the number of horizontal lines/curves? In any case, this answered it. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: It's in the definition of the height -  --h: calc((100vh - var(--l)) / 3); And it's also assumed in having only one of the right hand semi circles - but that could all be adusted if you wanted more.